# Emoji's in a changing label

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, label, emoji

I have a label that is constantly changing based upon what the user opens.

Our backend is sending the label from a list of possible responses.

I would like to know how to make some of these come in with an emoji and others not.

My thought would be to write some type of emoji code in the actual list like "Hey whats your name(winky face)"

And then when the front end receives it can make the conversion.

Comment: Just haven't found anything like this, short of putting the emoji code, or straight up dropping the emoji in via the shortcuts to the actual Xcode, but this won't work since the labels are not static.

Comment: do you want to add emoji in UILabel or UIButton text ?

Comment: UILabel that is pulling from:

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *question;

Comment: you can add emoji in string.

Comment: The string is being pulled from the backend though., So how should it be written in the backend for the frontend to the interpret it?

Comment: make multiple predefine cases and emoji's base on cases. add some example code to Answer  your question

Comment: lbQuestion.text = question;  (In the M file)

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *question; ((In the H file)

Comment: NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         g_userID, pUserID,
                         questionId, pQuestionID,
                         goodValue, pAnswer, nil];

Comment: #define pQuestionID                 @"question_id"
#define pQuestion                   @"question"

Answer (score 0):

How to add Emoji's in NSString or any other text in objective c or swift in Xcode.

```
NSString *question =@"Hey whats your name  ?";

lbQuestion.text = question;
```

1. Select location of emoji in the string.
2. Go to Xcode -> edit.
3. Select from menu Emoji's & Symbols
4. Or direct shortcut ^+command+Space.
5. Select any Emoji's.

`

```
NSString *newquestion= [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@" ?"];
//or 

question = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@  ?", question];
```

Comment: The questions are not being written on the frontend.

They are being pulled from the backend.

Comment: if you know which type of question then you can use `NSString stringWithFormat` to add Emojis at end.

Comment: like this `NSString *newquestion =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@  ?", question];` make some predefine case to select emojis

Comment: I understand, the problem is, we have like 1000 questions.

Would it be possible to drop a "\U0001F431" inside of the question?

Would that produce it?

Comment: If you want to add only one emoji inside all question then you can add simply by using `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@  ?", question];` or you can `[question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@" ?"];`

Comment: If you find my answer helpful to you then you can mark as selected.

Comment: just tried the 

[question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@" ?"];

Did not work for me, im going to investigate

Comment: `NSString *newquestion= [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@" ?"];` this is not work for you ?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?